# Construir un SET a partir de una fecha determinada JAVA

Tags: java

a la hora de devolver me salen los datos en blanco. Tengo las fechas guardadas en el otro main.

Ahora se nos pide que intentemos construir un conjunto `Set` con todos los nombres de productos adquiridos a partir de una fecha determinada. Para ello tendremos que implementar el método: `getProductosComprados` en la clase `Tienda`.

Este método recibe como parámetro una fecha `LocalDate` y a partir de ella, mediante la exploración de todas las compras que aparecen en los tickets, generará un objeto de tipo conjunto `Set` que contendrá los nombres `String` de cada uno de los productos que se han comprado desde esa fecha. Al tratarse de un conjunto, los nombres de los productos deberían aparecer una única vez.

Y el código que llevo:

```
public Set<String> getProductosComprados (LocalDate fecha) {
    Set<String> productosComprados= new HashSet<String>();

    for (String i: productosComprados) { 
        Set<String> productosComprados1 = productosComprados;
    }

    return productosComprados; 
}
```

El código de prueba es el siguiente:

```
//----------------------------------------------
        // Pruebas del método getProductosComprados
        // de la clase Tienda
        //----------------------------------------------
        System.out.print(Utilidades.cabecera("PROBANDO MÉTODOS DE LA TIENDA"));
        System.out.printf ("Probando getProductosComprados a partir del 11/02/2023: %s\n", tienda.getProductosComprados(LocalDate.of(2023,  2, 11)));
        System.out.printf ("Probando getProductosComprados a partir del 10/02/2023: %s\n", tienda.getProductosComprados(LocalDate.of(2023,  2, 10)));
        System.out.printf ("Probando getProductosComprados a partir del 04/02/2023: %s\n", tienda.getProductosComprados(LocalDate.of(2023,  2,  4)));
        System.out.printf ("Probando getProductosComprados a partir del 01/12/2022: %s\n", tienda.getProductosComprados(LocalDate.of(2022, 12,  1)));
        System.out.println();
```

Comment: *Este método recibe como parámetro una fecha LocalDate y a partir de ella, mediante la exploración de todas las compras que aparecen en los tickets...* ¿Dónde están las compras que refieres? En el método `productosComprados` está vacío. Ni siquiera se ve el contexto en que estás, quizá convenga un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable donde se vea todo el contexto. ¿`productosComprados` sería miembro de la clase que contiene el método `getProductosComprados()`? Si no lo es, el método debería recibir ese objeto en parámetro.

Comment: Buenas @A.Cedano
De todas formas, lo pongo en el código, muchas gracias

Comment: Pero es que eso no va a verificar nada, porque esto `Set<String> productosComprados= new HashSet<String>();` no tiene ningún dato. ¿Dónde se supone que llenas las *compras que aparecen en los tickets* como afirmas en la pregunta?

Comment: @A.Cedano son datos que están metidos en la clase de pruebas... Pone tienda.getProductosComprados(localdate.of(xxxx)) ahí es donde ponen los datos

Comment: Hola Matuto, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, debes adjuntar el contexto necesario, aunque el mismo esté en tu anterior pregunta, es que cada pregunta debe ser autocontenida.

Comment: Si no vemos el contexto difícilmente podremos ayudarte. ¿Qué es lo que hay en esa clase de pruebas que refieres y cómo llamas desde ella a `getProductosComprados()`? Y, no sé si entiendes lo que te vengo diciendo más arriba, el objeto que usas para el `for` dentro de `getProductosComprados()`está vacío.

Answer (score 0):

En la clase **Tienda** debes tener una lista de **Tiquet**, en la que vas cargando cada `tiquet` creado.

```
List<TiquetCompra> listaDeTiquets = new ArrayList<>();

public void crearTiquet() {
    TiquetCompra nuevoTiquet = blablabla;
    listaDeTiquets.add( nuevoTiquet );
}
```

y el método que te piden, que devuelve una lista de los productos comprados.

```
public Set<String> listaProductosComprados( LocalDateTime fecha ) {

       // creamos el Set que vamos a devolver  
    Set<String> productosComprados = new HashSet<String>();


       // creamos una lista auxiliar  
    List<Compra> listaCompras;

       // recorremos la lista de Tiquet  
    for( TiquetCompra tiq: listaDeTiquets ) { 

           // fechaA.isBefore( fechaB ), devuelve true si fechaA es anterior a fechaB.
           // le pasamos como parámetros la fecha del tiquet (tiq.getInstante()) y la fecha 
           // que recibimos como parámetro
        if( fecha.isBefore( tiq.getInstante() )) {

               // le pedimos al tiquet la lista de compras y la asignamos a la listaCompras
            listaCompras = tiq.getListaCompra();

            for( Compra com: listaCompras ) {
                   // recorremos la lista de compras y agregamos a nuetro Set, el nombre 
                   // del producto que obtenemos con getProducto(), no debemos preocuparnos 
                   // de los nombres duplicados, ya que la clase Set no agrega un nuevo 
                   // elemento si ya existe. 
                productosComprados.add( com.getProducto() );
            }
        }
    }
    return productosComprados; 
}
```

Si te queda alguna duda... ya sabes.

Comment: me da error en listaCompras = tiq.getListaCompras, porque incompatible types: List<Compra> cannot be converted to List<String>.

Comment: Si, tenes razón, me equivoque en la declaración, ya edite la respuesta, corregí eso y algunos nombres.

Comment: me sigue dando error... ahora en tiq.getInstante, me dice LocalDateTime cannot be converted to ChronoLocalDate

Comment: he estado viendo y es que getInstante es LocalDateTime y el parámetro que pedimos es LocalDate

Comment: Ya está corregido, por eso te pedía que agregaras las otras clases, no es lógico estar mirando esta publicación y la anterior para contestar, aparte de los errores que pueda cometer, ambos recibimos votos negativos...

Comment: muchas gracias y perdona. Un saludo

Comment: No tienes nada que agradecer, siempre es un placer ayudar.

Comment: puedes ayudarme con este? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/589290/cómo-crear-mapa-en-java?noredirect=1#comment1042073_589290