# ¿Cómo crear mapa en Java?

Tags: java

Al ejecutar la clase prueba04 me da valores, pero no son los que piden el ejercicio.

**ENUNCIADO**:

> En esta ocasión, tendremos que implementar para la clase Tienda el método: *getImportesPorFechas*.
> Este método explorará todas las compras realizadas para generar una estructura de tipo Map o lista de pares <clave,valor> (o <K,V>), donde:
>
> - las claves serán las fechas (`LocalDate`) en las que se hayan llevado a cabo compras;
> - los valores serán el importe total vendido en esas fechas (`Double`).
>
> Este método explorará todas las compras realizadas para generar una estructura de tipo Map o lista de pares <clave,valor> (o <K,V>), donde:
>
> - las claves serán las fechas (`LocalDate`) en las que se hayan llevado a cabo compras;
> - los valores serán el importe total vendido en esas fechas (`Double`).

```
public class Tienda {
private final String idTienda;
private final List<TicketCompra> listaTickets;

// Ejercicio 4: clasificación de ventas por fechas
    // -----------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Devuelve un Map con las cantidades totales facturadas cada fecha.
     * @return Map donde las claves son fechas y los valores las cantidades facturadas en esa fecha.
     */
    public Map<LocalDate, Double> getImportesPorFechas() {
    
    
    Map<LocalDate, Double> map = new HashMap<>(); 
    
    double monto= 0;
    LocalDate fecha;
    
    
    for (TicketCompra imp: listaTickets) {
        monto += imp.getImporte();
        fecha = imp.getInstante().toLocalDate(); {
        if( map.containsKey( fecha ) ) {
            monto += map.get( fecha );
        }
        map.put( fecha, monto ); }
       }
    return map;
}
```

Esta clase es Prueba04 que es donde se ejecuta el metodo getImportesPorFechas y donde están los valores del mapa fecha y
valor

```
    package tarea07.pruebas;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import tarea07.tienda.Tienda;

/**
 * Programa de pruebas para la clase <code>TicketCompra</code>: método <code>getImportesPorFechas</code>. 
 */
public class Pruebas04 {

    // Declaramos un constructor privado para que la clase no sea instanciable (es un programa "ejecutable")
    private Pruebas04() {        

    }

    /**
     * Programa principal.
     * @param args posibles argumentos desde la línea de órdenes (no se usa)
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  4. Prueba del método getImportesPorFechas de la clase Tienda
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        System.out.print(Utilidades.cabecera("4.PRUEBA DEL MÉTODO getImportesPorFechas DE LA CLASE Tienda"));
        System.out.printf("Fecha de realización de la prueba: %s\n", LocalDate.now().format(Utilidades.FORMATO_FECHA));
        System.out.println();

        //----------------------------------------------
        // Creación de objeto Tienda de prueba
        //----------------------------------------------
        System.out.print(Utilidades.cabecera("CREANDO TIENDA DE PRUEBA"));
        Tienda tienda =  Utilidades.CreaEjemploTienda();
        System.out.printf ("Creado ojeto Tienda de prueba: %s\n", tienda);
        System.out.println (tienda.toStringTicketsCompra());
        System.out.println();
        
        //----------------------------------------------
        // Prueba del método getProductosComprados
        // de la clase Tienda
        //----------------------------------------------
        System.out.print(Utilidades.cabecera("PROBANDO MÉTODOS DE LA TIENDA"));
        System.out.println ("Probando getImportesPorFechas");
        Map<LocalDate, Double> importesPorFechas = tienda.getImportesPorFechas();
        System.out.println ("Resultado obtenido:");
        if (importesPorFechas != null) {
            for (Entry<LocalDate, Double> parFechaImporte:importesPorFechas.entrySet()) {
                System.out.printf ("Fecha %s -> Importe %7.2f\n", 
                        parFechaImporte.getKey().format(Utilidades.FORMATO_FECHA), parFechaImporte.getValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Buenas. No llego a comprender cual es el objetivo del ejercicio. ¿Debes devolver el Map en la función con una serie de valores?

Comment: Buenas, tiene que devolver un map con las key (localdate) fecha de las compras y (double ) valores del importe total vendido

Comment: Claro, y lo que debes hacer es inicializar y rellenar de valores el map, ¿correcto? Si me confirmas, te respondo en unos minutos

Comment: @RuDaHee he puesto el main de la otra clase donde se ejecuta, donde se ven ahí los valores del mapa. Muchas gracias rudahee un saludo

Comment: Me parece que lo que estás haciendo es recorrer un mapa, no lo estás generando en el método. Para generar el método, debes agregar valores con put. Puede ser que no tengas nada dentro del mapa y por eso no te funcione.

Comment: Añade todo el código relevante. No pongas a la gente a adivinar por qué será que algo no funciona. Completa la pregunta y explica DE FORMA CONCRETA qué error tienes. "Este es mi enunciado y este código no funciona" no es concreto

Comment: @Alfabravo el problema es que el main me ejecuta pero no me da los valores del map.

Comment: Edita. Las. Preguntas. CUando te pregunten cosas en los comentarios. Puedes [edit] tooodo lo que quieras y va a ser visible para todos

Comment: @Alfabravo ya lo he puesto, muchas gracias y disculpa

Comment: Seguimos en el mismo juego, pones un enunciado y no agregas la información pertinente, si no agregas al menos la clase Tienda, no podemos ayudarte...

Comment: Cómo instancias `tienda`? el código de arriba es la clase Tienda? Están en el mismo package?

Comment: @MarcePuente ya lo he puesto

Comment: @Alfabravo ya lo he puesto

Comment: Aprendé a _especificar_. Pulsá en [edit] y explicá a qué te referís con _no funciona_: ¿no ejecuta? ¿da un error? De darse el error, ¿cuál es el error? Proveé la mayor cantidad de detalles posible para que sea más sencillo ayudarte. Leé [ask].

Comment: @MarcePuente lo acabo de actualizar, me da valores pero no los que me piden en el ejercicio

Comment: @Alfabravo lo acabo de actualizar, me da valores pero no los que me piden en el ejercicio

Comment: @padaleiana lo acabo de actualizar, me da valores pero no los que me piden en el ejercicio

Comment: @JakintsuIheslari lo acabo de actualizar, me da valores pero no los que me piden en el ejercicio

Comment: Complicás demasiado que se te ayude, das información tan de a poco... ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado (el que te pide el ejercicio)? ¿Cuál es el obtenido? De nuevo, leé [ask], y adjuntá un [repro]. Proveé **todos** los detalles necesarios para entender tu pregunta y dar ayuda útil.

Answer (score 4):

No te voy a dar el ejercicio resuelto, no porque me moleste hacerlo, sino porque no estás entendiendo las cosas más básicas, y ni siquiera preguntas, no parece haber un interés de tu parte por aprender, y si te seguinos "haciendo los deberes", nunca lo vas a lograr.

```
public Map<LocalDate, Double> getImportesPorFechas() {
      // creas el Map que vas a llenar para después devolver 
   Map<LocalDate, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Empieza con un for, que recorre listaDeTiquets.
A cada tiquet, le pide la lista de compras y la fecha.
Convierte la fecha de LocalDateTime a LocalDate (ver abajo).
Crea una variable **monto** (double) para guardar la suma de los importes.
Crea otro for (dentro del anterior) que recorra la lista de compras.
A cada compra le pides el importe y las sumas a la variable **monto**.
Cierras el for interno.
Después agregas esto:

```
if( map.containsKey( fecha ) ) {
    monto += map.get( fecha );
}
map.put( fecha, monto );
```

El if comprueba si el mapa contiene como *key*, la fecha del tiquet, si la tiene, suma el valor de esta con el acumulado en **monto**.
La sentencia **map.put()** agrega al mapa un nuevo elemento, si la *key* ya existe, lo reemplaza por el nuevo.
Cierras el primer for.
Retornas el **Map**.

Convertir de **LocalDateTime** a **LocalDate**, ejemplo:

```
LocalDateTime fechaA = LocalDateTime.of( 2021, 10, 10, 01, 10 );
String dia = fechaA.getYear() + "-"
             + fechaA.getMonthValue() + "-"
             + fechaA.getDayOfMonth();
LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse( dia );
```

Crea tu código, equivocate y estaremos aquí para ayudarte.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el post. Ahora me ejecuta el código y me da valores, pero no me da los valores que me tiene que dar.

Comment: @matuto es decir?

Comment: @Alfabravo me da otro tipo de valores... es que lo que no entendí es esta parte " A cada tiquet, le pide la lista de compras y la fecha.
Convierte la fecha de LocalDateTime a LocalDate (ver abajo).
Crea una variable monto (double) para guardar la suma de los importes.
Crea otro for (dentro del anterior) que recorra la lista de compras.
A cada compra le pides el importe y las sumas a la variable monto. "

Comment: Vamos, estamos caminando, y ya me ensañaste algo, el método **.toLocalDate()** no lo conocía, gracias, empezas bien, creas las dos variables, el for, inicializas **fecha**... y luego querés pedirle al tiquet (mal nombre **imp**, lleva a confusión), el importe... no lo tiene, si relees mi respuesta, ahí deberías crear otro for, que recorra la lista de compras que obtuviste con el primer for, y a cada compra le pedís el importe y se lo agregas a **monto**, un detalle, la variable **monto** se tiene que reiniciar a "cero" con cada iteración del bucle externo.

Answer (score 1):

¡Buenas Matuto!

En tu ejercicio en ningún momento estabas agregando datos a tu HashMap. Te dejo un código de ejemplo para agregar algunos datos de ejemplo, y con comentarios explicativos dentro.

```
public Map<LocalDate, Double> getImportePorFecha() {

    // Aquí inicializamos un valor el día 25 de Marzo.
    Map<LocalDate, Double> importes = new HashMap<>() {{
        put(LocalDate.of(2023,3,25), 50D);
    }};

    // Después vamos a simular 15 días de ventas seguidos (y vamos a cambiar los valores de cada día tambien)
    for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
        importes.put(LocalDate.of(2023, 4, i), (double) i * 10L);
    }

    LocalDate diaRepetido = LocalDate.of(2023, 4, 20);

    // Agregamos otro valor mas
    importes.put(diaRepetido, 1337D);

    // Y ahora agregamos un valor el mismo día, y por el funcionamiento de los HashMap, debería sustituir el valor.
    // Debido a que los HashMap no pueden contener claves repetidas, sustituye el valor de la existente.

    importes.put(diaRepetido, 1350D);
    
    // Ahora vamos a ver que hay dentro del HashMap.
    
    importes.forEach((fecha, importe) -> {
        System.out.println(fecha.toString() + ": " + importe + " €");
    });
    
    return importes;
}
```

Comment: la cosa es que los valores están en el main de prueba, es el segundo código que he puesto... lo que tengo que realizar es hacer un metodo para que los valores del main corran y den la ejecución

Comment: En mi comentario tienes todas las herramientas para resolver el ejercicio. :)

Comment: @matuto no se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer, de donde vienen los valores? dices que vienen del main pero en el main solo llamas al método getImporteFecha que devuelve un map vacio. "Este método explorará todas las compras realizadas para generar una estructura de tipo Map o lista de pares <clave,valor>", de donde salen las compras?

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ salen de la clase prueba04 que he puesto. Disculpa, muchas gracias

Comment: @matuto En qué parte dices que están los valores que quieres usar? Vemos que haces `CreaEjemploTienda` y luego `toStringTicketsCompra` pero no sabemos por qué probar con estos valores que te dicen no es lo que buscas. Recuerda que no sabemos nada más que lo que vemos :)