# Convertir LocalDateTime en LocalDate

Tags: java

ERROR: incompatible types: LocalDateTime cannot be converted to ChronoLocalDate

en el ejercicio me piden hacer una lista con ciertos valores. A la hora de hacer el código me da error porque la lista me la da con parámetro LocalDate y el .getInstante de otra clase donde se ejecuta el main es LocalDateTime. Pongo el código, muchas gracias.

```
public Set<String> getProductosComprados (LocalDate fecha) {
        
        Set<String> productosComprados = new HashSet<String>();
        
        List<Compra> listaCompras;
        
        for( TicketCompra tiq: listaTickets ) { 
             if( fecha.isBefore(tiq.getInstante())) {
                 listaCompras = tiq.getListaCompra();
                 
                 for( Compra com: listaCompras ) {
                     productosComprados.add(com.getProducto());
                 }
             } else {
             }
        }
        return productosComprados; }
```

Comment: Pon el error. Completo

Comment: @Alfabravo incompatible types: LocalDateTime cannot be converted to ChronoLocalDate

Comment: después de getInstante prueba llamando al método toLocalDate() tal que asi: if(fecha.isBefore(tiq.getInstante().toLocalDate()) { ... }

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ muchas gracias!!! Llevo no se cuantos días para resolverlo! Mil gracias

Comment: @matuto de nada!

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ y si no es mucho pedir jaja estoy también atascado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/589290/cómo-crear-mapa-en-java/589294?noredirect=1#comment1042035_589294 en este post. muchas gracias y un saludo